# Sorting numeric values mixed with alpha numeric values in mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have a column for residential numbers as

```
res_no
b1
a2
b11
c25
a11
a3
....
```

I want sort these values like

```
a2
a3
a11
b1
b11
c25 
...
```

Tried queries

```
ORDER BY CAST(substr(res_no,3) as UNSIGNED) asc 

ORDER BY CAST(res_no as UNSIGNED) asc
```

but nothing sorts like above answer

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is your exact form, you can just order by the first letter and then the numeric part (from letter 2 onwards):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
ORDER BY LEFT(res_no, 1),
         CAST(SUBSTR(res_no, 2) AS UNSIGNED);
```

Output:

```
res_no
a2
a3
a11
b1
b11
c25
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gq3LcxPUoiubGQkYKjuMZa/0)

If you're running a version of MySQL (or MariaDB) which supports `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, you can be more flexible in terms of how many leading letters there can be, or even whether the letters are at the end or not present at all:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
ORDER BY res_no REGEXP ('^[0-9]') DESC,
         CAST(res_no AS UNSIGNED),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(res_no, '(^[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]$)'),
         CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(res_no, '(^[0-9]+)|([0-9]+$)') AS UNSIGNED)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=792841e6f8f76cdc44481110543e7e1e)

Comment: if the res_no are like 111A,11B,20A  the above query not working @Nick

Comment: @Simba what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 10.1.35-MariaDB  @Nick

Comment: @Simba I've updated the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` query and demo to something I think will work for you. Please give it a try.

Comment: is there any way for 125,140,140A,142B,A1,B5 kind of sorting @Nick

Comment: Just to confirm, you want all numbers (e.g. 125), then all numbers with letters (e.g. 140A), then all letters with numbers (e.g. A1); and then within those groups, sort ascending by the letter then the number?

Comment: @Simba please see my edit. I think it does what you want.

Comment: How to sort values inside parathesis @Nick  view this ink https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985728/sorting-valuse-inside-paranthesis?noredirect=1#comment102379668_57985728