# Sorting valuse inside paranthesis

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a column for residential numbers as

```
res_no
-------
1a(1)
1a(2)
1c(2)
1a(3)
a1(1)
a1(a)
a1(2)
b1(2)
```

I want to sort this like below

```
res_no
------
1a(1)
1a(2)
1a(3)
1c(2)
a1(1)
a1(2)
b1(2)
a1(a)
```

How to do this kind of sorting in MySQL?

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you tried using `order by`

Comment: Are all the numbers in the exact form shown (i.e. letter, number, (letter/number); or number, letter, (number)) or are there other possible formats?

Comment: possible formats.I added new question regarding this please have look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023005/sorting-multiple-types-of-numbers-and-characters @Nick

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest:

```sql
SELECT res_no as res_no, 
   SUBSTRING(res_no,1,1) as _A, 
   SUBSTRING(res_no,2,1) as _B,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(  SUBSTRING_INDEX(res_no, ')', 1), '(', -1) as _C   
FROM test
ORDER BY 
_A,
_B,
_C
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` clause to sort.

query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable order by res_no;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you trying to achieve but this is the closest thing I can come up with.

```
SELECT yes_no, 
   SUBSTRING(yes_no,1,1) , 
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(  SUBSTRING_INDEX(yes_no, ')', 1), '(', -1)   
FROM new_table
ORDER BY
     SUBSTRING(yes_no,1,1),
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(  SUBSTRING_INDEX(yes_no, ')', 1), '(', -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will help you to get desired result. To get consistent result i used to trim rows. Here i separated table on the basis of first Alphabet/Digit

```
SELECT 
  dr.res AS res_no 
FROM
  (
    (SELECT 
      1 fake_order,
      TRIM(a.res_no) AS res,
      0 AS sub 
    FROM
      table_name_here AS a 
    HAVING res REGEXP '^[0-9]+' 
    ORDER BY res ASC) 
    UNION
    (SELECT 
      2 fake_order,
      TRIM(b.res_no) AS res,
      TRIM(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(res_no, ')', 1),
          '(',
          - 1
        )
      ) AS sub 
    FROM
      table_name_here AS b 
    HAVING res REGEXP '^[a-z]+' 
    ORDER BY sub ASC,
      res ASC)
  ) AS dr 
ORDER BY dr.fake_order ASC,
  CASE
    dr.fake_order 
    WHEN 1 
    THEN dr.res 
    ELSE dr.sub 
  END ASC ;
```